# How to perform batch multiplication in pytorch without bmm?

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm doing the online Computer Vision course by UMich and am new to PyTorch. One of the assignment questions is on batch matrix multiplication, where we have to find the batch matrix product with and without the bmm function. Here is the code.

```
    def batched_matrix_multiply(x, y, use_loop=True):
  """
  Perform batched matrix multiplication between the tensor x of shape (B, N, M)
  and the tensor y of shape (B, M, P).

  If use_loop=True, then you should use an explicit loop over the batch
  dimension B. If loop=False, then you should instead compute the batched
  matrix multiply without an explicit loop using a single PyTorch operator.

  Inputs:
  - x: Tensor of shape (B, N, M)
  - y: Tensor of shape (B, M, P)
  - use_loop: Whether to use an explicit Python loop.

  Hint: torch.stack, bmm

  Returns:
  - z: Tensor of shape (B, N, P) where z[i] of shape (N, P) is the result of
       matrix multiplication between x[i] of shape (N, M) and y[i] of shape
       (M, P). It should have the same dtype as x.
  """
  z = None
  #############################################################################
  #                    TODO: Implement this function                          #
  #############################################################################
  # Replace "pass" statement with your code
  z = torch.zeros(x.shape[0], x.shape[1], y.shape[2])
  if use_loop == True:
    for i in range(x.shape[0]):
      z[i] = torch.mm(x[i], y[i])
  else:
    z = torch.bmm(x,y)
  #############################################################################
  #                            END OF YOUR CODE                               #
  #############################################################################
  return z
```

I've managed to do it without bmm, but without using the torch.stack hint. I initialized a zeroes matrix 'z' with the dimensions of the output matrix and performed normal matrix multiplication for each batch using the for loop.

I'd like to know what the more efficient answer using torch.stack is.

Comment: What makes you think that using `torch.stack` would be a more efficient solution? I guess your solution (initialize the resulting matrix) is okay and isn't less efficient than stacking the results afterwards. The solution would be roughly: `z = torch.stack([torch.mm(x[i], y[i]) for i in range(x.shape[0])])`

Answer (score 0):

great question. I just tried solving this myself for two hours now. Here's my solution and it really speeds up the computation, as needed.

```
  if use_loop == False:
      z = torch.bmm(x,y) 
  else:
      z = torch.zeros(x.shape[0], x.shape[1], y.shape[2])
      for i in range(x.shape[0],2):
          z[i] = torch.stack([x[i] @ y[i], x[i+1] @ y[i+1]])
```

Hoped this helped!

Comment: I happen to do that assignment several days ago. Your solution is not correct. To be more precise: `z1 difference within tolerance:  False`

Comment: Could you elaborate? Would appreciate if you could share your solution then. It seemed to run properly on my end.

Comment: Here is the result I got with your code snippet with `use_loop=True`: 

CPU times: user 64 µs, sys: 18 µs, total: 82 µs
Wall time: 83.9 µs
z1 difference:  4.068337440490723
z1 difference within tolerance:  False

Comment: Berriel's comment shows the correct answer. The code could be run without error doesn't indicate that it does what you want. Run the Colab and the `z1 difference` should be at or near 0. The problem in your code is that `range(x.shape[0], 2)` doesn't contain any element since `x.shape[0]` is greater than 2. Thus the for loop is skipped. And, if the for loop is executed, you will probably have an error because `z[i]`'s shape is not compatible with `torch.stack([......])`. I'm not sure if the last sentence is correct, you can try and check it out.